# Azure Functions and helper functions

Tags: python, azure-functions

I've successfully deployed an Azure Function! But it fails.

```
Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CurrencyConversion'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 242, in _handle__function_load_request func_request.metadata.entry_point)
File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/site/wwwroot/CC_Timer/__init__.py", line 3, in <module> import CurrencyConversion as cc
```

So from the above error we can tell that the issue is importing my helper functions from CurrencyConversion.py into **init**.py. My code looks like such:

```
import CurrencyConversion as cc
import os
import azure.functions as func
```

My file structure is such:

```
CCTimer
├── __init__.py
├── CurrencyConversion.py
```

Can anyone help elaborate on the issue above? Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the official doc, there is a detailed description about how to import modules in your function code:[Import behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior).

> You can import modules in your function code using both explicit
>   relative and absolute references.

And under [unit test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing), you could find the sample import module from the folder.

So you could import with `from __app__.CCTimer import CurrencyConversion`.

**Note:** for now suppose there is a [bug with python 3.7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/374#issuecomment-480807993), so if you are using python 3.7, the explicit relative way is better.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 implicit relative imports are forbidden.

What you can do is `from .module import name`.
In your case for example
`from .CurrencyConversion import classname/funcname`

you can check the python3 docs
https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax